# Get ListCount counting only user view list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, custom-javascript

I have below code, to fetch the count of sharepoint list items to auto generate next item number by incrementing it. But somehow it's only fetching count of list items per user (list is protected to show only resp user's items). i would it instead have get list of all items (irrespective of user).
Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"type = "text/javascript" ></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
var clientContext = null;
var web = null;
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(AutoGenerate, "sp.js");

function AutoGenerate() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query></Query></View>');
    this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(listItems);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListItemsLoadSuccess),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {

    var AutoIncremental = "AA-XCSA-" + listItems.get_count();
    $("input[title^='Request ID']").val(AutoIncremental);
    $("input[title^='Request ID']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can use **ItemCount** property of the **List** to get the total item count.
I've tested with a list for which item level permission was enabled and found out that regardless what items the user have permission to, the total count is returning the same.

```
<div>
<input type='button' value='Get item count' onclick="javascript:GetListItemCount();"/>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ItemLevelPermission')";

var myData;

function GetListItemCount(){    


        $.ajax({
            url: url,  
            method: "GET",  
            headers: {  
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
            },

            success: function(data){
               
               //myData=data;

               alert("Total item count in the list: " + data.d.ItemCount);
                
            },

            error: function(error){
                   
           alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
                '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                  
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

rahman

I tried your code but somehow when clicked on button, wasn't giving anything. I tried to amalgamate both the codes but aint working either. can you please check, i am trying to assign the count value to variable and use it for next ID generation.

```
<div>
<input type='button' value='Get item count' onclick="javascript:GetListItemCount();"/>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var AutoIncremental = null;
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Data Setup')";

var myData;

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetListItemCount, "sp.js");

function GetListItemCount(){    


        $.ajax({
            url: url,  
            method: "GET",  
            headers: {  
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
            },

            success: function(data){
               
               //myData=data;

               alert("Total item count in the list: " + data.d.ItemCount);
               var AutoIncremental = "SDSR-" + data.d.ItemCount;
               $("input[title^='Request ID']").val(AutoIncremental);
               $("input[title^='Request ID']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                
            },

            error: function(error){
                   
           alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
                '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                  
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try using a "button" like in my example to see if you can make it work?  ItemCount  is a List property, so it should return a value as long as the user has access to it.

Comment: Another question, what kind of permission does the user have at the **List** level? For my example, user has "Contribute" permission at the list level, and Item-Level-Permission was set according to this [Article](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: @matiur-rahman hi, i was finally able to make it work, there was issue with list title. Bu t i am facing another problem, the counter is stuck at 2, its not updating when added new items and still showing old value

Comment: @MatiurRahman, I have updated my post with the working code & screenshot, where you could see that there are 3 items but counter is still showing 2. Please guide if i am missing something. I tried with my access (Full Control) and my users would have Contribute access to the site/list

Comment: Can you add one more item and see if it still returns the same count 2. My guess is that List.ItemCount is being cached and that's why it's not returning the correct value in your case. Another different between your code and mine is that I have this running on the View Page, not on NewForm.aspx or EditForm.aspx

Comment: @MatiurRahman .. you are right, its getting cached, when tried in another browser, returned correct data. is there a way i can handle cacheing issue ? i need it on new item page, as i am using it to generate ticket number. Thanks

Comment: If it's browser' caching, you might be able to handle. However, my concern is if SPO is caching it you don't have any control. Also, there might be other solution for creating ticket number. Have you searched for any other types of solution to generate ticket number? I will see if I can help on that

Comment: You can take a look into this [article](https://yarnthen.github.io/yarnthencohosking/tutorials/2017/08/01/unique-ticket-id-generator-in-sharepoint.html) describing how to create ticket numbers

Comment: will do .. thank you so much for your help .. really appreciate it