# Get ItemCount from Existing View

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, 2019

I have a Task list that I'm trying to query to get the total Active Tasks for the current user. There is a view already built that I would like to use.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/views/getbytitle('My Tasks')/ItemCount
```

However, it throws an error:

> Cannot find resource for the request ItemCount

Is there a way I can grab the item count from an existing view using the REST API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to get the items count for list view like you can get for list using `/ItemCount` endpoint.

**Workarounds**

**Solution 1** (Personally Recommended):

1. First get the `ViewQuery` for list view which stores the CAML query for list view. You can get it like:

   ```
   <siteUrl>/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/views/getbytitle('Active Tasks')/ViewQuery
   ```

   **Example Output**:

   ```
   <Where>
       <Neq>
           <FieldRef Name="Status" />
           <Value Type="Text">Completed</Value>
       </Neq>
   </Where>
   <OrderBy>
       <FieldRef Name="ID" />
   </OrderBy>
   ```
2. Using this ViewQuery, you can build CAML query and then fetch list items using [getItems()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245102(v=office.15)) endpoint (POST Method).
3. Count the number of items returned in 2nd step.

**Reference**: [How to get all items in a view using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135936/how-to-get-all-items-in-a-view-using-rest-api)

---

**Solution 2**:

If you want to reduce the number of REST calls then you can use this approach.

1. First take a note of all filters applied to list view
2. Get list items using `/items` endpoint by applying filters noted in 1st step, something like this:

   ```
   <siteUrl>/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/items?$filter=Status ne 'Completed'
   ```
3. Count the number of items returned in 2nd step.

**Note**: If you use this approach then you have to change `$filter` query every time you change the filter conditions from list view settings.

Comment: It looks like my ViewQuery for the Task list is malformed => ViewQuery: "'CompletedNot Applicable/>CompletedNot Applicable>"

Comment: Is it coming like this? Either it is malformed or not complete query. Can you add the response of `<siteUrl>/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/views/getbytitle('Active Tasks')/ViewQuery` to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get a direct item count from a view. You need to retrieve the items from the view and check **items.length** property to find the count.

You can refer to [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135936/how-to-get-all-items-in-a-view-using-rest-api) to find out the details

**ItemCount** property is at the **list** level
You can see [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286760/get-listcount-counting-only-user-view-list-items/286772#286772) to find out more

Comment: useful links thx